# How to stop an in-tree driver/ko from binding to a device without disabling such driver

Tags: networking, drivers, network-interface, pci

i'm having a particular in-tree device driver and i want to leave it enabled for a device (i.e. not blacking listing it for all), but just to stop it from binding to another device of a different PCI Device ID.

The particular situation is that, i have two NICs, RTL8168 (1GbE, DID `0x8168`) and RTL8125 (2.5GbE, DID `0x8125`). There is an in-tree driver `r8169` that claims to support both, but when the RTL8125 (2.5GbE) device is using this `r8169`, it operates at a degredaded performance (of 1GbE). I'm on the distro of ubuntu 20.04, in case of any distro-specific thing.

I wish to conitnue to use the in-tree driver `r8169` for the device RTL8168 (1GbE), but to use a different out-of-tree driver (`r8125`) for the device RTL8125 (2.5GbE).

I see that [this line](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.4/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169_main.c#L227) claims RTL8125's DID for `r8169`, so technically i could remove it then rebuild kernel, but I prefer to no go that route (for all the secure boot hassle)

I could manually rebind the drivers, but that won't persist over reboots by itself.

Would appreciate to hear advice on a proper way to override such driver binding.  Thanks! Below are the `lspci` output of those two devices in this particular example.

```
06:00.0 0200: 10ec:8125
        Subsystem: 10ec:0123
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
        Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at fc610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Region 4: Memory at fc620000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at fc600000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169, r8125

0a:00.0 0200: 10ec:8168 (rev 15)
        Subsystem: 1043:8677
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 36
        Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at fc504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Region 4: Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I did it:

- Let the system boot normally and let it bind the 8125 card to the 8169 driver
- Use a startup script of some sort to **unbind** the 8169 driver from the 8125 card and **bind** the 8125 driver to it

Example:

- Find the PCI address of the card through the command

  ```shell
  lspci -k
  ```

  In this example I assume the card is in the slot `0000:01:00.0`:
- Unbind PCI device `000:01:00.1` from `r8169` driver:

  ```shell
  echo 0000:01:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/unbind
  ```
- Then bind it to `r8125` driver:

  ```shell
  echo 0000:01:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8125/bind
  ```

Restart and reconfigure network interfaces as needed (`ip link up`, `ifconfig up`, etc.).

This way the 8169 cards remain bound to the `r8169` driver so everything works.